# WPF MeasureOverride is not called on custom panel resize (Width => MinHeight)

Tags: wpf, layout

I've made custom layout panel. I've implemented MeasureOverride and ArrangeOverride methods.

Here is how I'm using my panel.

```
<Window
    x:Class="TestWindow.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:TestPanel="clr-namespace:TestPanel;assembly=TestPanel"
    Title="MainWindow"
    Width="706"
    Height="200">
    <Window.Resources>
        <Style TargetType="Button">
            <Setter Property="Height" Value="40" />
            <Setter Property="MinWidth" Value="120" />
            <Setter Property="HorizontalAlignment" Value="Stretch" />
            <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Stretch" />
        </Style>
    </Window.Resources>
    <ScrollViewer>
        <Border BorderBrush="Red" BorderThickness="1">
            <TestPanel:ShrinkPanel Background="Aqua" MaxColumns="4">
                <Button Content="Text 1" />
                <Button Content="Text 2" />
                <Button Content="Text 3" Height="75" />
                <Button Content="Text 4" />
                <Button Content="Text 5" />
                <Button Content="Text 6" Height="100" />
                <Button Content="Text 7" />
                <Button Content="Text 8" />
                <Button Content="Text 9" Height="75" />
            </TestPanel:ShrinkPanel>
        </Border>
    </ScrollViewer>
</Window>
```

Everything works fine, except MeasureOverride is not called when my panel is resized. Height property is always NaN, while ActualHeight changes, but does not cause measurement.

How can I force Measure on resize?

I've subscribed to SizeChanged event and called MeasureOverride like this

```
private void This_SizeChanged(object sender, SizeChangedEventArgs e)
{
    Measure(e.NewSize);
}
```

but this code does not seem to be used anywhere in the framework. I think specifying minimum allowed Height depending on Width should be a very common task.

So, what is the right way to remeasure and thus set DesiredSize (or MinHeight/MinWidth?!) on resize.

Comment: Hello, could you add the code for the panel?

Comment: Not sure what you mean by "when my panel is resized". Unless I'm missing something you're always going to be measured with infinity since you're within a ScrollViewer. If you want to be measured with the actual available size and be within a ScrollViewer then you have to be the direct child of the ScrollViewer (not within the Border like you have in your snippet) and you have to handle scrolling (i.e. implement IScrollInfo and set CanContentScroll on the ScrollViewer to true).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is the Scroll Viewer: It seams that the  Scroll Viewer it is giving infinity Height/Width to the items that contains, so the Desired Size of your panel is Infinity. You can try Disable the vertical bar of the Scroll Viewer, or in the your custom panel treat specifically the case when the Desired Size is Infinity.
Hope this help you.